# How to read characters from a file until a space and store that as one string (c)?

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgetc

I need to read all the information from a line in a file before a space and store it as a string, how do I do that?

File example:

```
Biology A 4.0
Tennis B 1.0
```

etc (I need the letter and number later and I know how to store them fine, just the dang string is giving me trouble)

So far I have

```
int main (void)
{
    FILE* grades;
    char className[10];
    char currChar;
    int i = 0;

    grades = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
    if (fgetc(grades) != ' ')
    {
        currChar = fgetc(grades);
        className[i] = currChar;
        i++;
    } 

    /* what I want to happen here: if a character is not a space, it is
        appended to className. I thought if i was the position in the array,
        I could add in one character at a time
    */
    printf("%s", className); // check to make sure it worked
}
```

what the result is: the symbol that looks like a ? in a hexagon

Thanks for any help, I'm open to trying other ways too. I tried using fgets with the length i equal to the number of characters before a space found in a previous while loop, but that printed the part directly after the area I wanted.

Comment: 'className is not initialized, adding in a char to one that is uninitialized has no useful outcome.  Neither does attempting to printf("%s... an array of chars that is not securely NULL terminated.

Comment: 'if (fgetc(grades) != ' '' dumps a char from the input buffer.  It is lost.

Comment: When dealing with lines of text, try to resist the temptation to declare buffers smaller than, say, [256], (unless you are on a RAM-restricted embedded system).

Comment: Just read the char once into your 'currChar', then decide what to do with it.  Is it a line-terminator char?  Is it a space?

Comment: It's just a space. The file given has a bunch of lines that say things like "Biology A 4.0", I want to read in the word "Biology" to "className"

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by NULL terminated. Also, why exactly shouldn't I make it smaller than [256]? I know thats 2^8 but the name is only going to be up to 10 characters. I'm not arguing or anything, just wondering

Comment: C 'strings' are just arrays of chars that are terminated with a NULL char.  Lacking a length attribute, and without a terminator, calls that handle strings, (like printf("%s..),  don't know where the end is.  ' the name is only going to be up to 10 characters' - who cares?  The C tag is filled with thousands of posts where developers have overrun their little buffers by one byte, (eg. to put in the terminating NULL).  Stop counting chars and just declare [256], (or, or course, larger if required), for everything.

Comment: Thank you. To null terminate it, I made an else statement else
 {className[i] = '\0';
 return 0;}

Comment: See this:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968927/run-time-check-failure-2-in-c-file-processing

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) ?

Something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE* grades;
    char className[10];
    char grade;
    float marks = 0;

    grades = fopen("grades.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(grades,"%s %c %f", className, &grade, &marks)>0) {
        printf("%s %c %f\n", className, grade, marks); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! though now I'm angry with myself because I literally thought using something like this earlier fscanf(grades, "%s %c %f", className, letterGrade, credits) but it messed up for whatever reason and you got that to work so thank you thank you

Comment: the reason was lack of & ... sigh. Also sorry, this is my first post. This is also why the formatting was off before... my programming assignment was saved by (ssj2?) Goku.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with reading from a file up-to the first `space` character with `fgetc`, however, there are several problems with:

```
if (fgetc(grades) != ' ')
{
    currChar = fgetc(grades);
    className[i] = currChar;
    i++;
}
```

When you call `fgetc(grades) != ' '`, a character is read from `grades` and then the *file-position-indicator* is advanced to the next character. So when you call `fgetc` inside the `if` statement, you read a character and then the *file-position-indicator* is advanced in preparation for reading the next character. When you then call `fgetc` again in the body of the if statement (`currChar = fgetc(grades);`), you read the *second* character in the file. It seems rather obvious from your question, that your intent was not to *skip-a-character* and then begin reading with the next.

When you read input with any *character-oriented-input* function (e.g. `getchar`, `fgetc`, etc.) there are three primary things you are responsible for: (1) insuring you do not attempt to write more characters to your storage variable than it will hold; (2) check for any *sentinel* or terminating character you wish to stop the read with; and (3) checking that you have not reached the end of the input stream.

Putting those pieces together you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCN 10

int main (void)
{
    FILE* grades = NULL;            /* initialize variables */
    char className[MAXCN] = {0};
    int currChar = 0;               /* currChar is an int   */
    int i = 0;

    /* open and validate file */
    if ((grades = fopen("grades.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed 'grades.txt'.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read from grades until 1st space */
    while (i + 1 < MAXCN && ((currChar = fgetc (grades)) != ' ' && 
                              currChar != EOF)) {
        className[i++] = currChar;
    }
    className[i] = 0;   /* null-terminate */

    printf("\n className: %s\n\n", className);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** when you stop reading on any character, the next read will resume on the next character in the input stream. So you will need to empty any characters that remain (in the line, etc...) if you want to begin your read at any than other than the next character. Also note, when you open a file with `fopen`, you should validate that the open actually worked before proceeding to read from the file.

**Input**

```
$ cat grades.txt
Homeroom grades are include below
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgetc_grades

 className: Homeroom
```

Hopefully this will help you get started, let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thanks, I used a snippet from above, but in the code shouldn't it be  `(currChar = fgetc (grades)) != ' ' &&  currChar != EOF)`?